# Where can I find "Correlation and Causation" by Wright 1921?

Tags: publications, research-process

I've been looking for where I can read: Wright, S. (1921). "Correlation and causation". *Journal of Agriculture Research*. **20** (7): 557-585.

I've tried the following without success.

- Going directly to the Journal
- Google search engine
- Google Scholar
- Research Gate
- Search tools at my university's library
- Asking a research librarian for assistance

Articles by the same author in a similar time period are available, such as [Systems of Mating. I. The Biometric Relations Between Parents and Offspring](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1200501/pdf/111.pdf). It isn't clear to me why the particular article I wish to read is difficult to obtain.

Is this article available somewhere?

Comment: Did you ask a research librarian at your university's library?

Comment: This isn't really a question suited to this site, but... the Bodleian Library catalogue reveals that this is a US Department of Agriculture publication, and not obviously related to the current Journal of Agricultural Research (which appears to be a Pakistani outfit).  http://solo.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/permalink/f/89vilt/oxfaleph013202870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your paper, via Google Books:

https://books.google.co.ao/books/about/Journal_of_Agricultural_Research.html?hl=pt-PT&id=lNNdIV_qpwIC&utm_source=gb-gplus-shareJournal

Check page 557 for the first page of the paper (if you download the pdf file, go directly to page 738).

Answer (score 0):

People often neglect to ask for help from a research librarian at a local university. In fact, even a village library, such as that where I live, has a librarian with "contacts" at nearby libraries, including university libraries.

Research librarians are trained to find such things and also have a network that they can use to chase down things. They are a valued resource that every research should become familiar with.

They can not only uncover difficult to find books and papers, they are excellent at taking descriptions of research "needs" and translating them in to the papers that cover them.